# IIS cpu is restricted on default configuration

Tags: .net, iis, asp.net-core, iis-10

When I'm running a .net core website, I noticed that the CPU is not using all of its capacity.

The CPU never gets higher than 14%, and 1GHz. Even if the taskmanager states that the CPU is capable of 3.2GHz.

IIS is configured with the default settings, so the `limit` property of the `application pool` is set to `0`. Which should not limit the CPU usage ([as per docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add/cpu#configuration)). The `action` property is also set to `NoAction`.

I tried increasing the worker processes, but without luck.
Is there a way to allow an increased CPU usage, so that the website responds faster?

**EDIT**

To clarify what I mean with speeding up the response time, here is what causes the delay:

When the user uploads a pictures, those pictures are analysed for duplicates and shrunk to several smaller dimensions.

The whole process of manipulating and processing the images is done in an `async`
way. However, if I use IIS the CPU isn't boosed when the images are processing, causing the browser to hang.
When I'm using Visual Studio (when developing), I see a brief boost of clock frequency and CPU usage.

Comment: You probably get some misunderstanding. CPU usage has little to do with response time (or I should IIS will use as much as needed). Run a profiler to analyze what exactly happens for your web app to respond and that can tell you how to speed it up.

Comment: Added an Edit to clarify the problem.